# Interaction with a paired Bluetooth Low Energy device using Python under Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python, bluetooth

I have a [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) (BLE) peripheral (an [Adafruit Feather nRF52840 Express](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4062?gclid=CjwKCAjwzPXlBRAjEiwAj_XTEfsz-C54Cy1lVUZz-RxApGNBGdateiTD_q5e59UylDdNWaRBTh6yABoCoS8QAvD_BwE)) and would like to send the data to a Windows 10 computer and read it using Python. I can pair the device using the device manager but can't work out how to interact with it using Python 3.7.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.rototron.info/circuitpython-nrf52840-pi-tutorial/)?

Comment: Windows CircuitPython Drivers [are here](https://learn.adafruit.com/welcome-to-circuitpython/installing-circuitpython).

Comment: thanks @Anaksunaman  getting it to work with Raspberry Pi is easy. Windows seems to be more of a problem with BLE. I can write the circuitpython code necessary for the Adafruit Feather nRF52840 Express to pair with no problem. The issues is how to read the data it sends to Windows 10 after it pairs. Nothing in Python 3.7 seems to do the trick. I have tried pybluez-win10 with no luck and also tried bleak but couldn't get it to install properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [PyBluez](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez) or [bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak).

To discover your peripheral using **bleak**, all you have to do is:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import discover

async def run():
    devices = await discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```